# Contar lineas de codigo de un programa fuente python

Tags: python-3.x

tengo una tarea en la cual no tengo idea de como encararla, consiste en escribir una funcion recursiva que cuente la cantidad de lineas de codigo de un programa fuente escrito en python, ignorando comentarios, lineas en blanco y docstrings.

```
def contar_lineas(archivo, inicio=0):
    for linea in archivo:
        if linea > 0:
            if str(linea).isalnum() and '#' not in linea:
                inicio+=1
            if '""""""' in linea or '' in linea:
                inicio-=1
    return inicio
```

Comment: ¿Recursiva o iterativa? La tuya es iterativa (y la de la respuesta de @anythingg)

Comment: Tendria que ser recursiva, pero por eso no sabia como hacerla

Answer (score 0):

Para contar las líneas tienes que recorrer el programa línea por línea, descartando todas las que no son ejecutables:

- líneas en blanco.
- líneas dentro de un docstring.
- líneas que son exclusivamente comentarios.

Como los docstring pueden ser multilínea, hay que llevar un indicador que nos señale cuando estamos dentro de uno, para descartar esas lineas.

Para facilitar la comprobación, la función imprimira la versión "filtrada" del programa de entrada.

```
def contar(programa):
    with open(programa, "r") as f:
        version_simple = []
        dentro_doc_string = False
        for linea in f:
            #   Eliminar los whitespaces al principio y al final
            linea = linea.strip()
            if not linea:  # Línea vacía
                continue
            if linea[0:3] == '"""': # Aqui comienza o termina un docstring
                # Caso: Docstring en una sola linea
                if linea[-3:] == '"""' and len(linea) != 3:
                    pass  # Un docstring en una linea
                else: # Docstring multilinea
                    dentro_doc_string = not dentro_doc_string
                continue
            if dentro_doc_string: # Dentro de un docstring no contamos lineas
                continue
            if linea[0] == '#': # Tampoco contamos los comentarios
                continue
            # Contar lo que queda
            version_simple.append(linea)
    numero = 1
    for lin in version_simple:
        print(f"{numero} {lin}")
        numero += 1

    return len(version_simple)
```

**Demo**

Archivo test.py

```
def funcion(x):
    """
    Una funcion
    """

    """Otro docstring"""

    x = x + 1 # Incrementar
    linea = "Titulo\n"\
            "------"
            
    # Retornar
    return x
```

probamos con

```
print("resultado = ", contar("test.py"))
```

produce:

```
1 def funcion(x):
2 x = x + 1 # Incrementar
3 linea = "Titulo\n"\
4 "------"
5 return x
resultado =  5
```